# Why does my custom UILabel not update correct data in my Swift app?

Tags: swift, uilabel

I have a small iOS app in swift which fetches stock price information from a public API. It fetches the latest price for a stock and saves the previous price for the stock. It then goes on to calculate the absolute price difference as latest price - previous price and the relative price difference percentage as (absolute price difference / previous price) * 100.0. However, when I update the custom UILabels to show the absolute and relative price differences I get 0.0 printed in the UILabel objects' text fields even though I can see the latest price changing in the UILabel object for the latest price updates. The relative and absolute price difference do go up and down turning green and red respectively but occasionally they will stick at 0.00% and (0.00) even though I can see the latest price changing. I have tried printing out latest price, absolute price, relative price and absolute price from the cellForRowAt delegate method which proves the correct values are being calculated but I cannot figure out why the correct values are not reflected in the UILabels. All displayed values are calculated to two decimal places as best as I know how.

Here is my cellForRowAt method in my custom table view controller class;

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CompanyStockCell", for: indexPath) as! CompanyStockCell
        
        cell.symbolValue.text = companyStockInfo[indexPath.row].symbol
        
        var latestPrice = companyStockInfo[indexPath.row].price
        latestPrice = round(latestPrice * 100.0) / 100.00
        cell.priceValue.text = String(format: "%.2f", arguments:[latestPrice])
        
        if let stockPrice = previousStockPrices[indexPath.row] {
            let previousPrice = round(stockPrice * 100.0) / 100.0
            var absoluteDifference = latestPrice - previousPrice
            absoluteDifference = round(absoluteDifference * 100.0) / 100.0
            absolutePriceDifferences[indexPath.row] = absoluteDifference
            
            var relativeDifference = 0.0
            if previousPrice != 0.00 {
                relativeDifference = (absoluteDifference / previousPrice) * 100.0
                relativeDifference = round(relativeDifference * 100) / 100.0
            }
            if indexPath.row == 0 {
                print(latestPrice, previousPrice, absoluteDifference)
            }
            
            if absoluteDifference > 0.0 {
                cell.priceDirectionImageView.image = UIImage(systemName: "arrowtriangle.up.fill")
                cell.priceDirectionImageView.tintColor = .systemGreen
                cell.relativePriceDiffValue.text = String(format: "%.2f%%", arguments: [relativeDifference])
                cell.relativePriceDiffValue.textColor = .systemGreen
                cell.absolutePriceDiffValue.text = String(format: "(%.2f)", arguments: [absoluteDifference])
                cell.absolutePriceDiffValue.textColor = .systemGreen
            } else if absoluteDifference < 0.0 {
                cell.priceDirectionImageView.image = UIImage(systemName: "arrowtriangle.down.fill")
                cell.priceDirectionImageView.tintColor = .systemRed
                cell.relativePriceDiffValue.text = String(format: "%.2f%%", arguments: [relativeDifference])
                cell.relativePriceDiffValue.textColor = .systemRed
                cell.absolutePriceDiffValue.text = String(format: "(%.2f)", arguments: [absoluteDifference])
                cell.absolutePriceDiffValue.textColor = .systemRed
            } else {
                cell.priceDirectionImageView.image = UIImage(systemName: "diamond.fill")
                cell.priceDirectionImageView.tintColor = .white
                cell.relativePriceDiffValue.text = "0.00%"
                cell.relativePriceDiffValue.textColor = .white
                cell.absolutePriceDiffValue.text = "(0.00)"
                cell.absolutePriceDiffValue.textColor = .white
            }
        } else {
            cell.priceDirectionImageView.image = UIImage()
            cell.priceDirectionImageView.tintColor = .white
            cell.relativePriceDiffValue.text = ""
            cell.absolutePriceDiffValue.text = ""
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Here is a screen shot of the UI;
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Could it be that the price difference is so low that it always goes into your `else` block which sets the text to 0.00 ?

Comment: @ShawnFrank No, because even if absolute price difference is 0.01 or -0.01 it will always be caught in the correct catch block.

Comment: @shawnFrank Its almost as if the UILabel class is not rendering the correct values.

Comment: I am looking at the screen shot above, where is this data currently showing ?

Comment: @ShawnFrank For Apple stock AAPL is displayed in the first table view cell. The latest price is shown in orange and to the right is relative price difference as a percentage and to the right of that is the absolute price difference in parenthesis.

Comment: Ok now I feel I understood the issue. When the price changes, sometimes the difference value and percentage labels do not update ? The price label changes but it's these other two that seem problematic - correct ?

Comment: @ShawnFrank Yes I can see the latest price changing but sometimes the relative and absolute prices are just stock at 0.00% and (0.00) respectively.

Comment: That could probably because of precision. If the difference is `0.004` and below, you will see `0.00`. From the rounding logic I see `round(0.004 * 100)/ 100` gives you `round(0.4)/100` which becomes `0/100`. The difference has to be above 0.005 for some change in the label to occur I feel. Unless you see a change bigger than this and still it shows 0 ? Probably share some values of current price, previous price where it still shows 0 and I can try to run the same calculation at my end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242820/discussion-between-stephen501-and-shawn-frank).